# css less mixin rem calculator without being orientated to font or something

Tags: css, less

Morning everyone i have the following mixin and i would like to transform it into a global one. What i mean is without settings the margin i want to use it for font-size for example .. or for anything else that you might want to set it into rem / em units. I'm new to less and preprocessors and i was wondering if someone from here might help me out changing the code. thank you very much for your time.

```
.marginSizeCalc(@sv) {
  @sizeValue: unit(@sv);
  @remValue: (@sizeValue / @font-size-base);
  margin: unit(@sv,px);
  margin: unit(@remValue,rem);
}
```

Comment: You should post your "solution" as an answer below and then accept it, rather than posting a solution in the question. Either that, or delete the question all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to solve the problem... and i think it's even better than setting margin or font or anything else inside the mixin.

```
.marginSizeCalc(@sv) {
  @sizeValue: unit(@sv);
  @remValue: (@sizeValue / @font-size-base);
  @toRem: unit(@remValue, rem);
}
```

How To:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: @headings-font-family;
    font-weight: @headings-font-weight;
    color: @headings-font-color;
    margin: @remValue;
    margin: @toRem;
    .marginSizeCalc(@gutterWidth);
}
```

Update:

```
.marginSizeCalc(@sv, @db) {
  @sizeValue: unit(@sv);
  @divideBy: unit(@sv);
  @remValue: (@sizeValue / @divideBy);
  @toPx: unit(@remValue, px);
  @toRem: unit(@remValue, rem);
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: @headings-font-family;
    font-weight: @headings-font-weight;
    color: @headings-font-color;
    margin: @toPx;
    margin: @toRem;
    .marginSizeCalc(@gutterWidth, 2);
}
```

Comment: Your solution appears to have an error for the first `margin` returned. Assuming `@font-size-base` is `10px` and `@sv` is `12px` your first `margin` comes out `1.2px` instead of `12px` because you use the straight `@remValue` not the `unit(@sv, px)` calculation like the original code.

Comment: erm sorry i forgot to change the vars inside that code.. i've been playing with it for couple of hours and the first version was based on fonts.. so i didn't change much. the example that i posted is for margin. usage and i see now what's the problem. you are right scottS changed the way it works. did a small upgrade haven't tested the code yet.

Comment: I'm thinking you want to use the `@toPx` for the first `margin` and also your update has a second parameter for the mixin which you would need to pass in your "How To" example.